# Does the method Session.close() will interrupt the current running being executed called by Session.run() in tensorflow in another thread?

Tags: tensorflow

The two threads share the same session.
thread-1 runs the code:

```
session.run()
```

thread-2 runs the code:

```
session.Close()
```

Can thread-2 interrupt the running of thread-1 or block until the finish of thread-1.

Comment: I guess, this depends if you are reaching the same instance. how did you declare your session?
`public static var session = new tf.Session();`?

Comment: yes, the two threads share the same session.